# How to omit the last comma while importing to access DB?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Well, I have successfully coded my unformatted text data. I used comma as a delimiter and if I am posting it here so that it can help students like me.

```
Try
    Using Reader As New TextFieldParser(Application.StartupPath & "\data.txt")
        Reader.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth
        Reader.SetFieldWidths(20, 20, 1, 2)
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not Reader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                Dim oWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\FormattedData.txt")
                For Each newString In currentRow
                    oWrite.Write(newString & ",")
                Next
                oWrite.WriteLine()
                oWrite.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Now I have a question too: How can I omit the last comma from the output while importing to access database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (that I have found) is to write the comma for the last record on the next pass, but don't do it on the first loop:

```
Dim fFirstEntry As Boolean = True

For Each newString In currentRow
  If fFirstEntry Then
     fFirstEntry = False
  Else
    oWrite.Write(",")
  End If
  oWrite.Write(newString)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code help is like knife in butter. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each newString In currentRow
    sb.Append(newString).Append(",")
Next
sb.Length -= 1
oWrite.Write(sb.ToString())
```

Note that the StringBuilder is more efficient than direct string manipulation. The latter generates a lot of garbage on the heap, which has to be collected by the garbage collector later.